# Grid of thread blocks and Multiprocessor

Tags: cuda, multiprocessor

The [CUDA programing guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_1/toolkit/docs/NVIDIA_CUDA_C_ProgrammingGuide_3.1.pdf) states:

> The CUDA architecture is built around a scalable array of multithreaded Streaming Multiprocessors (SMs). When a CUDA program on the host CPU invokes a kernel grid, the blocks of the grid are enumerated and distributed to multiprocessors with available execution capacity. The threads of a thread block execute concurrently on one multiprocessor, and multiple thread blocks can execute concurrently on one multiprocessor. As thread blocks terminate, new blocks are launched on the vacated multiprocessors.

Does it mean that if I have a video card of 2 multiprocessor x n-cuda cores and if a launch a kernel like

```
MyKernel<<<1,N>>>(sth);
```

One of the multiprocessors will be idle, since I'm launching a single block of N threads?

Comment: That is precisely what it means.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct.

In all currect CUDA architectures, a block is only ever scheduled and run on a single multiprocessor. If you run one block on a device with more than one multiprocessor, all but one of those multiprocessors will be idle.

Comment: if I want to avoid the idling of any SM, should the execution configuration of grid size be at least equal to SM count?

Comment: @FelixXu: No that is not sufficient. You need to run at least the maximum number of resident blocks per SM times the SM count